# SIGSEGV while creating a parser-tree

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, lex

I am trying to create a parser-generator using flex/bison. This is my partial parser.y code:

```
func_definition : type_specifier ID LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN compound_statement
                 {
                    $$=new Symbol_info();
                    $$->code+="PROC:"+ $2->symbol+"\n";

                    if($2->symbol!="main")
                    {
                        $$->code+="PUSH AX\n";
                        $$->code+="PUSH BX\n";
                        $$->code+="PUSH CX\n";
                        $$->code+="PUSH DX\n";
                    }

                    $$->code += $6->code ;

                    if($2->symbol!="main") {
                        $$->code+="POP DX\n";
                        $$->code+="POP CX\n";
                        $$->code+="POP BX\n";
                        $$->code+="POP AX\n";
                    }

                    fprintf(parseLog, "GRAMMER RULE: func_definition -> type_specifier ID LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN compound_statement  \n"); 
                 }
                ;
```

And this is my partial lex.l code.

```
{id} {
    Symbol_info *s= new  Symbol_info(yytext, "ID");
    yylval = (YYSTYPE)s;

    return ID;
}
```

And this is my partial symbol_table.h code

```
class SymbolInfo{
    string type;
    string symbol;
public:
    string code;
    SymbolInfo *next;


    SymbolInfo(){
        symbol="";
        type="";
        code="";
    }
    SymbolInfo(string symbol, string type){
        this->symbol=symbol;
        this->type=type;
        code="";
    }
    SymbolInfo(char *symbol, char *type){
        this->symbol=string(symbol);
        this->type= string(type);
        code="";
    }

    SymbolInfo(const SymbolInfo *sym){
        symbol=sym->symbol;
        type=sym->type;
        code=sym->code;
    }
```

So, when I create a program, I get a SIGSEGV segmentation fault. (Address boundary error). It appears that I get that error when I try to access the `yylval` returned to me by the lex function.

Comment: Pardon for the basic question, but why are you casting here: `(char *)"ID"`?  If you removed the cast, what compiler error are you trying to conceal?

Comment: The casting isn't necessary really. My bad.

Comment: And what is your semantic type? Why do you need the cast in `yylval = (YYSTYPE)s;`?

Comment: @rici I have `extern YYSTYPE  yylval` in parser.y and lex.l. My YYSTYPE is Symbol_info*. I am casting to ensure that the symbol passed from lexer to parser is of the same type. Maybe it's not necessary.

Comment: That cast is dangerous, then, because it could suppress an error message which would let you know that the semantic types are incompatible between the lexer and the parser. (Say, for example, one of them was `int` instead of a pointer.)

Comment: You're right. I'm updating my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run this code on an Ubuntu 64-bit instance (Ubuntu 17.10). I don't know why but the same code runs fine on a 32 bit system (Ubuntu 14.10).

Maybe it's because of the large Integer sizes. [Here is the code](https://github.com/desertSniper87/CSE310/tree/master/4_code_generation) if you're interested.